# numpy and ROOT (numpy arrays management)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, root-framework

I want to plot some numpy arrays in a ROOT TGraph (using this contructor https://root.cern.ch/root/html/TGraph.html#TGraph:TGraph@4), but I got an unexpected result. Given this code:

```
import numpy as np
from ROOT import TGraph
import math

ac = np.empty([4,4], np.dtype('float64'))
# just filling with some float values
for i in range(0,len(ac[:,1])):
    ac[i,1]= (1/9.*float(i+1)+10)


print type(ac[:,1])
print len(ac[:,1])
# calling the TGraph constructor
rplot2 =TGraph(len(ac[:,1]),ac[:,1],ac[:,1])
```

the output is:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    rplot2 =TGraph(len(ac[:,1]),ac[:,1],ac[:,1])
TypeError: none of the 11 overloaded methods succeeded. Full details:
  TGraph::TGraph() =>
    takes at most 0 
  [I suppress here some non-relevant output]
  TGraph::TGraph(Int_t n, const Int_t* x, const Int_t* y) =>
    could not convert argument 2
  TGraph::TGraph(Int_t n, const Float_t* x, const Float_t* y) =>
    could not convert argument 2
  TGraph::TGraph(Int_t n, const Double_t* x, const Double_t* y) =>
    could not convert argument 2
```

while if I declare a monodimensional array:

```
import numpy as np
from ROOT import TGraph
import math

ac = np.empty(4, np.dtype('float64'))
# just filling with some float values    
for i in range(0,len(ac)):
    ac[i]= (1/9.*float(i+1)+10)


print type(ac[:])
print len(ac[:])
# calling the TGraph constructor
rplot2 =TGraph(len(ac[:]),ac[:],ac[:])
```

the output is:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
4
```

That is OK. I can fix the first behaviour doing:

```
rplot2 =TGraph(len(ac[:,1]),np.array(ac[:,1]),np.array(ac[:,1]))
```

but I cannot understand why. Also, do you have an idea for another workaround?

Comment: Probably useful google keywords: numpy contiguous copy

Comment: Si I forwarded the question to the CERN ROOT forum and here is the answer I got: PyROOT only passes flat, 1-dim arrays, as that is the only thing that can be handed through a pointer. ( https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=19632 )

Comment: i was going to do that but I didn't have an account for that forum. Thank you @AsenChristov . So the point is that in Python `ac[:,1]` is not a 2-dim array

Comment: I agree, I'll keep pushing for answers in the CERN ROOT forum. And I'll let you know.

Comment: I got some responses in the ROOT forum, but I cannot say I understand them. here is a link to the thread: https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=19632